# Allow end user to add tag to a particular post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking for the following feature in wordpress (.org) based blogs

"After a post is published, allow the end user to their won custom tag to a post they want. So, the publisher might have added a tag "football" to a post, but the reader might also want to tag it to "read later" , so that he can have all the posts that he want to read later tagged with "read later". "

In short , how to have a reader add their own tags to a post. One prerequisite could be that the reader will have to register with the blog site.

Alternatively, if someone can suggest any theme which supports this feature it would be good.

Thanks,
Tejas.

Comment: @Reigel : i meant wordpress.org

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WordPress.com won't allow anything like this -- anything you would need to do (forms to submit the data change, for example) would be disallowed by their services, as it's pretty locked down to heavy customization.

Comment: Hi, I have just edited my question.. I meant wordpress.org . the site which allows create websites for blogging.