# How to add custom tags box in wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, tags, wordpress-theming

now by default in Wordpress post (add new or edit) admin page are box named "Tags".

In my template i want to separately show tags for "Actors" and "Director", so i need two different tag boxes in admin.

Or it's immposible?

Answer (score 0):

similar questions: [Allow end user to add tag to a particular post in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14544954/allow-end-user-to-add-tag-to-a-particular-post-in-wordpress) and here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/letting-others-add-tags?replies=3

I think this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/ will help you. I has a taxonomy field type and it should be possible to register the metaboxes based on user rules, see; http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/registering-meta-boxes-since-4-3-6/